# Looking for a D3 way of drawing a mean line for a multil-series line chart

Tags: d3.js

I followed D3 [multi-series line chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) example and could successfully draw it. Now I need to add a line which is `mean` or `average` of all the lines drawn in the chart. Consider following points are plotted on chart to draw two lines:

```
Line 1 : [x:10, y:10], [x:20, y:20], [x:30, y:10]
Line 2 : [x:10, y:10], [x:20, y:18], [x:30, y:15]
```

Then mean line would be :

```
Mean : [x:10, y:(10+10)/2], [x:20,y : (20+18)/2], [x:30,y:(10+15)/2]
```

Is there a direcy way of drawing this mean line in `D3` or i'll have to compute the mean values for `y` and draw a new line?

Hope this makes it clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`d3.mean`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_mean) to compute this. The easiest way is to simply add another element to `cities`:

```
cities.push({
  name: "mean",
  values: data.map(function(d) {
    return {date: d.date,
      temperature: d3.mean(color.domain().map(function(e) { return +d[e]; } ))};
  })
});
```

Full example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7925423).